# If two functions are equal almost everywhere on a measurable set, then they are equal on it?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on a measurable set $E$. Is it true if $f=g$ almost everywhere on $E$, then $f=g$ on E? Here, measurable means "Lebesgue measurable."

When it is a closed interval, it works. But after it I can't go further.

How can I prove or disprove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; consider the set $E = [0,1] \cup \{2\}$. Two functions which agree on $[0,1]$ but differ on the single point $2$ are almost everywhere equal, but not equal.

Comment: Those functions would be continuous ?

Comment: @zebullon, a function on $[0,1] \cup \{2\}$ is continuous if and only if it is continuous on $[0,1]$. You can check this directly using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition if you want.